Android Webview not passing header enrichment parameters
I am trying to create a simple android app containing a webView that loads and opens a url whitelisted by the mobile operator to allow header enrichment injection. We did proper tests with mobile internet and the process went smoothly on mobile chrome browser, however, when used in a webView inside the android app, the injection is not working.
It is still a simple android app with the following files:
AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestHe"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

MainActivity.kt:
package com.testHe.app

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.webkit.CookieManager
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.URL


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        prepareWebView()
    }

    private fun prepareWebView() {
        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)

        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)

        webView.settings.apply {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            allowFileAccess = true
            allowContentAccess = true
            allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
            mixedContentMode = MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
            domStorageEnabled = true
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                safeBrowsingEnabled = false
            }
        }

        webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient() {

        }

        webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                    //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "page Loading: $url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                if(request?.requestHeaders != null) {
                    request.requestHeaders.forEach { action ->
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "header, key: ${action.key}, value: ${action.value}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "headers are null for url: ${request?.url?: ""}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
            }
        }

        /*lifecycleScope.launch {
            val htmlData = getHtmlData()
            webView.loadData(htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }*/

        //webView.loadData(htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8");

        webView.loadUrl(operatorUrl)
    }

    private suspend fun getHtmlData(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val google = URL(operatorUrl)
        val `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(google.openStream()))
        var input: String?
        val stringBuffer = StringBuffer()
        while ((`in`.readLine().also { input = it }) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(input)
        }
        `in`.close()

        return@withContext stringBuffer.toString()
    }
}

PS: operatorUrl is a placeholder for the actual web operator url. In the code it is the actual url.
I tried both loadData and loadUrl methods of webview with no success.

Header enrichment does only work for HTTP (without TLS) therefore you can use apps like PCAPdroid to capture the traffic and look at it in Wireshark. Then you can compare the requests and responses of your app with those created by Chrome.

Interesting, will give it a try

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.CookieManager
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val operatorUrl = "https://your.operator.url"  // Replace with your operator's URL

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    prepareWebView()
}

private fun prepareWebView() {
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)

    webView.settings.apply {
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        allowFileAccess = true
        allowContentAccess = true
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
        mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        domStorageEnabled = true
        userAgentString = WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(this@MainActivity)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            safeBrowsingEnabled = false
        }
    }

    webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {}

    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
            return true
        }
    }

    webView.loadUrl(operatorUrl)
 }
}


Hey, just tried your solution both user agents cases and both didn't work

ok are You check line menifest
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

now check i updated my code

still didn't work :(
